# Prediction failed: contents must be scalar

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have successfully trained, exported and uploaded my 'retrained_graph.pb' to ML Engine. My export script is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder

input_graph = 'retrained_graph.pb'
saved_model_dir = 'my_model'

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
  # Read in the export graph
  with tf.gfile.FastGFile(input_graph, 'rb') as f:
      graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
      tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

  # Define SavedModel Signature (inputs and outputs)
  in_image = graph.get_tensor_by_name('DecodeJpeg/contents:0')
  inputs = {'image_bytes': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(in_image)}

  out_classes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
  outputs = {'prediction_bytes': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(out_classes)}

  signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
      inputs=inputs,
      outputs=outputs,
      method_name='tensorflow/serving/predict'
  )

  with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    # Save out the SavedModel.
    b = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(saved_model_dir)
    b.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                               [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                               signature_def_map={'serving_default': signature})
    b.save()
```

I build my prediction Json using the following:

```
# Copy the image to local disk.
gsutil cp gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/tulips/4520577328_a94c11e806_n.jpg flower.jpg

# Create request message in json format.
python -c 'import base64, sys, json; img = base64.b64encode(open(sys.argv[1], "rb").read()); print json.dumps({"image_bytes": {"b64": img}}) ' flower.jpg &> request.json

# Call prediction service API to get classifications
gcloud ml-engine predict --model ${MODEL_NAME} --json-instances request.json
```

However this fails with the response:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"contents must be scalar, got shape [1]\n\t [[Node: Deco
deJpeg = DecodeJpeg[_output_shapes=[[?,?,3]], acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method=\"\", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device=\"/job:l
ocalhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"](_arg_DecodeJpeg/contents_0_0)]]\")"
}
```

Any help appreciated, I'm so close I can taste it :D

Comment: Maybe it's because the output tensors don't have the `_bytes` [suffix](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict#binary_data_in_prediction_input)?

Comment: Nope, same issue. I have updated Save_model script though

Comment: The gcloud command is essentially sending a json body with "instances" field which is the list created from all the inputs in the input json file. In this case there is only one. So it is sending

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @billiout afraid not, I ended up using Azure Container Instances

Answer (score 0):

The server will decode and batch all the inputs. So the input to your graph is essentially `[base64_decode("xxx")]` where you actually want to feed `base64_decode("xxx")` since the op takes a string type tensor. Server-side assumes the shape of input as `[None, ]` i.e. the first dimension can be anything for batching. In your case, `[None]`. You might want to create a tensor of that shape and then feed that into the op.

Comment: Thanks, I tried multiple variations of placing None in the input but none made a difference. Are you able to expand with a code example? I'm just trying to use online prediction for the model trained in TensorFlow for poets tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this line:

```
 in_image = graph.get_tensor_by_name('DecodeJpeg/contents:0')?
```

```
inputs = {'image_bytes': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(in_image)}
```

The shape here is scalar. Can you make sure you create input with shape `[None]`

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/trainer/model.py#L364